# How to use grammar-check for python in view in django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have installed `grammar_check` in a `virtualenv` and the I created a `django` project. Then in a my view I imported `grammar_check` and used it on some text but the issue is that I am getting import error. I don't understand what is the problem here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\saqib\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\threading.py",
 line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "c:\users\saqib\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\Lib\threading.py",
 line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autor
eload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\commands\runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\manage
ment\base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks
\urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\utils\funct
ional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\Saqib\Desktop\tbw\code\pro\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolv
ers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'gcpro.urls' d
oes not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file
 then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

Here is my view function:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import grammar_check

# Create your views here.
def check(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html')

def output_text(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        name= request.GET.get('q')
        tool = grammar_check.LanguageTool('en-GB')
        texts = name
        matches = tool.check(texts)
        name = grammar_check.correct(texts,matches)
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'result': name})
```

EDIT:
`gcpro.urls`

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('checker/', include('checker.urls')),
]
```

`checker.urls`

```
# users/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('check/', views.check, name='check'), 
    path('text/', views.output_text, name='outputtext'), 
]
```

This is the structure of project:
project

- checker

  - urls.py
  - views.py
  - and other files
- gcpro

  - urls.py
  - settings.py
  - and other files
- manage.py
- db.sqlite3
- templates
- static

If this is not the way to import an external tool or I am doing any other thing the wrong way please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Can you also post your `gcpro.urls` file contents?

Comment: I have added the code above

Comment: And what is `checker.urls` like? And where, with respect to `gcpro.urls`, is it located?

Comment: I have added the checker.urls and also project sturcture.

Comment: The two things I notice is that 1/ you don't have a `urls.py` in your base: `gcpro.urls` appears to be your root url, yet it 's located inside an app, and 2/ you include `check.urls` from `gcpro.urls`, which is located outside of the `gcpro` app. I'm not sure whether that's really an issue, but it may be something to look at.

Comment: Everything seems okay so far to me. Can you also update the original post with the **full** views.py file? From the urlconf it seems that you omitted some of the code.

Comment: it is not the issue. 
`
def output_text(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        name= request.GET.get('q')
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'result': name})`
If i use this view the the project runs fine. the error is occuring after i import and use `grammar_check` in view

Comment: Nope, something else is funky in your project. I copied all your posted code into a blank project and it works fine. Only thing I can think of without looking at the whole project is - maybe you have a file `grammar_check.py` somewhere in your project?

Comment: @wanaryytel https://pypi.org/project/grammar-check/ I installed `grammar_check` from here. and when i import it and use it then I am getting the error

Comment: No idea, if it's working correctly, but it's working. Do you have a folder or a file named `grammar_check` somewhere in your project?

Comment: no not file I installed it like from the link I posted in the comment using this : `pip install --user --upgrade grammar-check`

Comment: If you try to import `grammar_check` in Django shell (`manage.py shell`) , does it work?

Comment: yes in shell it is giving the correct output without any error

Comment: apparently I am getting this error even if i do this the view `text = 'try'`. any idea what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue was not related to any code but the error was occurring due to inconsistent spacing. I was using sublime and code appeared to be perfectly indented. But when I debugged the code step by step I found that there was an inconsistent space. Although I am not sure why it was giving an import error instead of an inconsistent space error.